# Knockout rebinding resets the HTML

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

With knockout, if a rebinding takes place, why is the HTML reset to its initial state? Look at the following code (http://jsfiddle.net/mgs_jsfiddle/KNnmC/)

```
<div data-bind="with: person">
   <p>person <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName"/></p>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: moveNext">moveNext</a>
</div>

$(function() {
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.person = ko.observable({ firstName: "first"});
        self.moveNext = function() {
            self.person({ firstName: "second"});
        };
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    $("input").css("background-color", "#ffff00");
});
```

If the anchor is clicked, the input element looses its background color. Why isn't just the value changed?

Update: I extended the jsFiddle to show that the `with` is responsible for regenerating the HTML. See Dirk's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `with` on an observable always rebuilds the HTML if it is bound to an observable and you change the observable. Just like a `foreach` would if you add or remove elements. I don't know the specific reasons why you change the background color with jQuery, but I'm pretty sure there is a better 'knockout' way of doing this.

In example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KNnmC/66/

```
<div data-bind="with: person">
   <p>person <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName, style: { background: hasBeard ? 'yellow' : 'red' }"/></p>
</div> 
<div>
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: moveNext">moveNext</a>
</div>

$(function() {
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.person = ko.observable({ firstName: "first", hasBeard: true});
        self.moveNext = function() {
            self.person({ firstName: "second", hasBeard: false});
        };
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

Comment: As always, the question is only a shortened version of the real code. In the real code there is no Javascript that changes the background color. I the real code the input element is transformed into a widget via a custom knockout binding. And this binding, more specifically its init method, is executed more than I exepcted. The reason for it being executed several times is the same reason as in the sample given above.

Comment: The `with` is indeed responsible for rebuilding the HTML. I have extended the JSFiddle to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Move background declaration before the `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());`

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="with: person">
   <p>person <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName"/></p>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: moveNext">moveNext</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {       
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.person = ko.observable({ firstName: "first"});
        self.moveNext = function() {
            self.person({ firstName: "second"});
        };
    };
    $("input").css("background-color", "#ffff00");
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KNnmC/64/

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be done in the real code. There the input element is transformed into some widget with the help of a custom knockout binding. And this binding's init is run multiple times, once for each revinding. But the underlying problem is the same, when compared to this explicit css styling in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is happening because `firstName` is not observable, and you are basically asking Knockout to rebuild the template inside the `with` each time.

Instead, define a model similar to this:

```
$(function() {       
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.person = { 
            firstName: ko.observable("first")
        }
        self.moveNext = function() {
            self.person.firstName("second");
        };
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    $("input").css("background-color", "#ffff00");  
});
```

Comment: Then when moving to the next person, a lot of statements would have to be written. In the real code, the object that gets stored into "person" is a complex object with many properties. And I would like to simply execute a single statement, handing over the original object.

Comment: @dirk says it pretty well in his answer. If you use the `with` binding then the inner template will be regenerated when the person is updated. What I do in cases like this is use an `attr` binding to set the `class` of the element based on the view model, so I would have a view model property which produced different style classes based on the state of the data.